# Who is this character in the second Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice trailer?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the most recent [Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice trailer](https://www.facebook.com/batmanvsuperman/videos/442964285904157/) (apologies, this link will take you to Facebook), we see this character:

> [image]

.

> Based on his physical appearance, I assumed it was [Doomsday](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Doomsday) but I don't think Doomsday has heat vision, which this fella seems to have.

So do we know who he/she is?

Comment: Alternative theories to my answer include Abomination from *The Incredible Hulk*, the Cave Troll from *The Lords of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring* and one of the titular characters from the new *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles* film without a mask.

Comment: The cave troll would be cool, he definitely didn't get enough screen time in LOTR.

Comment: Looks like he's bad CGI guy to me.

Comment: My bet is, that's General Zod with some mutations all over his body to render him even stronger performed by Lex Luthor.
However I have no evidence to back it up, besides the fact that the frame before this character appearance shows Lex Luthor receiving the body of General Zod in a lab.

Comment: I want to edit the question to say *(Apologies, this link will take you to Facebook and to a trailer that tells you the plot of the entire film.)*

Comment: @Praxis got for it 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**That's Doomsday.**

In the comics, [Doomsday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_%28comics%29) is a supervillian who was created on Krypton in ancient times, a long time before it was destroyed.

From the Wiki article;

> In a cruel experiment involving evolution, intended to create the perfect living being, the alien scientist Bertron released a humanoid infant (born in vitro in a lab) onto the surface of the planet, where he was promptly killed by the harsh environment. The baby's remains were collected and used to clone a stronger version. This process was repeated over and over for decades as a form of accelerated natural evolution. The agony of these repeated deaths was recorded in his genes, driving the creature to hate all life.

However, this was not the origin of the creature in *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice*.

> In the film, Doomsday is created by Lex Luthor combining the corpse of General Zod from *Man of Steel* with his own human genetic material, via a Kryptonian machine on one of Zod's spacecraft. Luthor indirectly names the creature when he tells Superman that it is "your doomsday" while setting it loose in Metropolis.

This explains the presence of heat vision, which Doomsday does not have in the comics as far as I am aware.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. General Zod with some mutations that Lex made on him.

Comment: It was ok, but could have been much evolved after getting hit. **won't spoil for anyone** O:-)